# Finding the url for this xml file in an input

Tags: html, css, xml, input

http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/noaatidepredictions/NOAATidesFacade.jsp?Stationid=8721138

This website has the current tides for my area, they provide the information in XML format which you can see via the download XML button on the right hand side of the page...

I want to bring this data into my site but i am unable to locate the absolute path to this xml file because they setup the button like an Input.

Comment: This is not really related to programming , feels like it belongs in Super user .

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox:

1. Click the `XML` button and save the XML file.
2. Press CTRL+J to open the `Downloads` window.
3. Right-click `8123462.xml` (the file you downloaded), and click `Copy
   Download Link`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/noaatidepredictions/NOAATidesFacade.jsp?datatype=XML&Stationid=8721138&text=datafiles%252F8721138%252F05122011%252F258%252F&imagename=images/8721138/05122011/258/8721138_2011-12-06.gif&bdate=20111205&timelength=daily&timeZone=2&dataUnits=1&interval=&edate=20111206&StationName=Ponce%20Inlet,%20Halifax%20River&Stationid_=8721138&state=FL&primary=Subordinate&datum=MLLW&timeUnits=2&ReferenceStationName=GOVERNMENT%20CUT,%20MIAMI%20HARBOR%20ENTRANCE&HeightOffsetLow=%2a1.00&HeightOffsetHigh=%2a%201.18&TimeOffsetLow=33&TimeOffsetHigh=5&pageview=dayly&print_download=true&Threshold=&thresholdvalue=) 
I found this by saving the file using chrome and `right clicking` on the download and selecting `copy link address`